# REGEX - JavaScript / Blockly

Tags: javascript, regex, blockly

I have two (or more) different export from our system in raw data. I would like to separete it by using regex without using IF foreach case.

**Bellow are two examples:**

1. <14>Apr 29 10:00:00 nimble1-A NMBL: Array:nimblegroup Type:14883
   Time:Fri Apr 29 10:00:00 2022#012 Id:8234 Target:nimble2-nimble1
   Version:6.0.0.300-956221-opt Message:Successfully created a snapshot
   of the volumes associated with volume collection nimble2-nimble1
   schedule test on synchronous replication partners pool-nimble2 and
   pool-nimble1.
2. <14>May  1 00:53:01 nimble1-A NMBL: Group:nimblegroup Type:1016
   Time:Sun May  1 00:53:01 2022#012 Id:9106 Object Id:- Object: Access
   Type:su Client IP:Console Status:Succeeded
   Version:6.0.0.300-956221-opt Message:Elevating user privilege to
   admin

In the first log I need to get only the **Message**. But in the othercase I need to get **Object, Type, Client IP, Status, Message**.

I expect that I need to use **? in regex**, but I dont know how without using IF for every case.

[Blockly image example here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCVz6.png)

Thank you, for your help.

Comment: Can you include the actual outputs in the post from the 2 examples you provided? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Structure is the same, but data inside are always different.  There are two actual outputs. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some ideas how to do? Maybe using Lookaround regex?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, you have above entries as strings.

With one single regular expression, it will be hard to do that. I personally would prefer a mix of a regular expression and [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and try to make a regular object out of it first.

Something like:

```js
var entriesRaw = [
    '<14>Apr 29 10:00:00 nimble1-A NMBL: Array:nimblegroup Type:14883 Time:Fri Apr 29 10:00:00 2022#012 Id:8234 Target:nimble2-nimble1 Version:6.0.0.300-956221-opt Message:Successfully created a snapshot of the volumes associated with volume collection nimble2-nimble1 schedule test on synchronous replication partners pool-nimble2 and pool-nimble1.',
    '<14>May 1 00:53:01 nimble1-A NMBL: Group:nimblegroup Type:1016 Time:Sun May 1 00:53:01 2022#012 Id:9106 Object Id:- Object: Access Type:su Client IP:Console Status:Succeeded Version:6.0.0.300-956221-opt Message:Elevating user privilege to admin'
];

var entries = entriesRaw.map(function(entry) {
    return entry.split(/((?:Array|Client IP|Group|Id|Message|Object(?: Id)?|Status|Target|Time|Type|Version):)/g).reduce((acc, chunk, i, chunks) => {
        if(chunk.slice(-1) === ':' && i < chunks.length - 1) {
            var tmp = {};
            tmp[chunk.slice(0, -1)] = chunks[i + 1].trim();
            
            return Object.assign({}, acc, tmp);
        }
        
        return acc;
    }, {});
});

console.log(entries);
```

This way you have all of entries parsed into an array of objects with key-value pairs and you can access them.

The trick is to do backtracking inside of the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), because this way the split chunks are part of the resulting array.

The problem with your entries is, that their syntax is hard to parse, so you have to come up with each key as a literal string in the regular expression.

If you need additional help, feel free to ask. :-)

Comment: Thank you! And how to add to blockly? If i have a string with some values and I need the right regex that take value if exist in regex zero or once (character ?) or the value will be ignored.

Comment: I am not sure how to add it to blockly. But what you have now is an object with key-value pairs, which you can use for your next step, adding it to blockly. You can now easily test whether a key exists, by: `if ('Type' in entry) { ... }`

This way you know whether `Type` exists in your entry. Or you can easily modify my code to provide a default value. (Maybe `null`.)

Comment: Maybe using lookaround regex?